# How can I get the location of a UIButton or UILabel inside a UITable?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have buttons in all of the `UICellViews`. When these buttons are pressed, some actions are fired. Things have worked fine until now.

How can I get the location of one of these button relative to the visible area on the screen? Do you have any ideas (or tutorials) on how to achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean relative to the window when you say *"relative to the visible area on the screen"*?

Comment: yea exactly thats what i mean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the method [`-convertRect:toView:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCEAJCI) of `UIView`.

```
CGRect frameInWindow = [button convertRect:button.bounds toView:viewController.view];
```

Here is a little test:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame];

    UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 300)];
    [self.view addSubview:parentView];

    UIView *childView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    [parentView addSubview:childView];

    CGRect rect1 = [childView convertRect:childView.bounds toView:self.view];
    // 200, 200, 100, 100 => correct

    // Other tests for the discussion of @H2CO3's answer.

    CGRect rect2 = [childView.superview convertRect:childView.frame toView:self.view];
    // 200, 200, 100, 100 => correct
    CGRect rect3 = [childView convertRect:childView.frame toView:self.view];
    // 300, 300, 100, 100 => wrong
}
```

Comment: so i used this to get the exact position of the button inside tableview which is inside uiview: CGRect rex=[button convertRect:button.bounds fromView:self.tableView.superview];

Comment: @user - You probably mean `toView` and not `fromView`.

Comment: by the way, the coordinates are negative numbers unless a button scrolled up so it origin is outside of upper screen part

Comment: yeah right toview is the right one to use otherwise one get negative numbers :D thanks very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `frame` property of a view to get its position relative to its superview:

```
CGRect frame = someView.frame;
CGPoint topLeftCorner = frame.origin;
```

If that's not sufficient (i. e. you want to get the frame of the view relative to any other view, not just its superview), you can use the various conversion methods:

```
CGRect relativeFrame = [view convertRect:view.bounds toView:anotherView];
```

See [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for further info.

Comment: Also shouldn't that be: `[view.superView convertRect:view.frame toView:anotherView];`? or `[view convertRect:view.bounds toView:anotherView];`?

Comment: @sch I also edited my answer, you can now revoke your downvote.

Comment: Sorry for downvote. It was temporary while the answer is not fixed :)